# Gun Mettle update and Killstreaks

Tags: team-fortress-2

**Can killstreaks be applied to the gun mettle skins for tf2?**

I'm trying to add a specialized kit to my skinned smg, but it won't let me.

I'm just making sure it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

**As far as I'm aware, you can use killstreak kits on the weapons as long as they correspond to their weapon type.** There are already quite a few skins that have killstreaks on them being sold on the Community Market.

If you can't add the kit on it, it may most likely be due to a different reason. I would suggest you try later.

Comment: They were bugged for a bit, but Valve has since fixed it.

Comment: @Powerlord Which patch was it?

Comment: Well, apparently it only affected certain weapons.  Revolvers and Pistols were fixed in the [July 8 update](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=17476). Shotguns and SMGs were fixed in the [July 6 update](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=17436).  Still, that's 4 of the 10 decorated weapon types, so nearly 50%.